# Why my sidewaystable is not working well?

Tags: sidewaystable

This works in another LaTeX template.
But today I move the table to another one.
And the first one can be fully seen.

Any hint is appreciated.

BTW: I'm using class

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
```

[image]

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{Performance of LC \& HE \& FFT}\label{Performance_FFT_line_hist}
%   \centering
    %\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Wall time (s)} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{BW (GB/s)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{System BW}\\

        \cline{2-4} \cline{5-9} 



        &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU}&SSD(s)&NDP2CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\

        %   &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&&CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ }\\
        \hline
        App&LC&HE&FFT&LC&HE&FFT&All&All&LC&HE&FFT\\
        \hline
        CS  &NA/0.98&NA/0.13 & NA/2.05 &NA/37.76&NA/26.15&NA/0.11  &108 &36 &36&26.15&0.11\\
        \hline
        SANS    &16.67/0&1.98/0 & 132.60/0  &2.22/$+\infty$  &1.72/$+\infty$ & 1.80e$^{-3}$/$+\infty$ &3 &36     &2.22 &1.72& 1.80e$^{-3}$ \\
        \hline
        SFNS      &13.45/0&1.14/0 &3.02/0  &2.75/$+\infty$  &2.98/$+\infty$ & 0.08/$+\infty$ &3 &36     &2.75 &2.98 &0.08  \\
        \hline
        ANS      &0.46/0&0.06/0   &3.68/0  &80.43/$+\infty$  &56.67/$+\infty$  &0.06/$+\infty$   &108 &36  &80.43&36&0.06 \\
        \hline
        FNS      &0.37/0& 0.03/0 &0.08/0  &100.00/$+\infty$ &113.33/$+\infty$ &2.91/$+\infty$  &108 &36 &100.00  &36&2.91 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    %\end{threeparttable}

    \caption{Energy efficiency of  LC \& HE \& FFT }\label{Energry_comparison_FFT_Lin_His}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Server Only (Watt) } &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{ Energy Consumption} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Energy Efficiency}\\
            %   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ (Watt)} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}   \\
            \cline{5-6} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Watt)}&active&idle &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Joule)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(MB/Joule)} \\
            \hline
            App&LC&HE&FFT&All&All &LC&HE&FFT&LC&HE&FFT\\
            \hline
            CS &0       &0      &0       &613.70  &30.33   &601.43  &79.78 &1258.10  &63.00 &43.64 &0.19 \\
            \hline
            ANS &207.50 &207.50 &207.50 &613.70   &30.33    &109.40  &14.27 &875.21 &346.33 &243.98  &0.27\\
            \hline
            FNS &421.20 &743.40 &259.56 &613.70   &30.33    &167.07  &23.21 &23.19  &226.78 &150.00 &10.29\\
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}

    \end{threeparttable}

    \caption{Performance of k-NN\_2 \& k-NN\_6 \& k-NN\_8}\label{Performance_kNN_268}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Wall time (s)} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{BW (GB/s)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{System BW}\\
            \cline{2-4} \cline{5-9} 


            %   &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&&NDP& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\

            &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU}&SSD(s)&NDP2CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\

            %   &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&&CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\
            \hline
            k-NN\_&2&6&8&2&6&8&All&All&2&6&8\\
            \hline
            CS  & NA/17.22&NA/31.33&NA/47.45 &NA/7.55&NA/4.15&NA/2.74  &108 &36 &7.55&4.15&2.74 \\
            \hline
            SANS & 825.50/0.62  &1843/0.62&2354/0.62  & 0.16/209.68&0.07/209.68&0.06/209.68 &3 &36     &0.16&0.07&0.06 \\
            \hline
            SFNS &36.31/0.62  &34.39/0.62&32.83/0.62    & 3.58/209.68&3.78/209.68&3.96/209.68  &3 &36    &3  &3&3  \\
            \hline
            ANS &22.93/0.62     &51.21/0.62&65.40/0.62    &5.67/209.68&2.54/209.68&1.99/209.68    &108 &36  &5.67&2.54&1.99 \\
            \hline
            FNS &1.01/0.62      &0.96/0.62& 0.91/0.62     &128.71/209.68&136.42/209.68&142.86/209.68  &108 &36 &108&108&108 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}


        %               \begin{tablenotes}
        %%                  \footnotesize
        %%                  \item[] * can be 2, 6, or 8; $^{\mathrm{a}}$ represents k-NN.
        %               \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}


    \caption{Energy efficiency of k-NN\_2 \& k-NN\_6 \& k-NN\_8}\label{Energry_comparison_k_NN}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Server Only (Watt) } &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{ Energy Consumption} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Energy Efficiency}\\
            %& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ } &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}   \\
            \cline{5-6} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Watt)}&active&idle &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Joule)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(MB/Joule)} \\
            \hline
            K\-NN\_&2&6&8&All&All&2&6&8&2&6&8\\
            \hline
            CS &0&0&0 &613.70& 30.33&10568 &19227 &29120 &12.60&6.92&4.57  \\
            \hline
            ANS &207.50&207.50&207.50 &613.70& 30.33&5815.10 &12541&15916 &22.89&10.61&8.36\\
            \hline
            FNS &420.53&429.85&431.87&613.70& 30.33&817.06 &803.46&782.29 &162.93&165.68&170.17\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}


\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable and show us some (fictional) data in the tables. We need to see how the tables are created ...

Comment: Your code works well in a standard `article` or `book` documentclass, we need to know which documentclass you're using. Please add your preamble to reproduce the problem.

Comment: \documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
I am using the "sample-acmsmall.tex" in this link :https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/tree/master/samples

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems your tables in your `sidwwaystable` is too wide for your used class `acmart`.

After breaking it into two parts with adding

```
\end{sidewaystable} % <=================================================
\begin{sidewaystable} % <===============================================
```

and adding

```
\vspace{0.5cm} % <======================================================
```

to get a better distance between two tables there is only one thing missing. I added (see documentation of package `rotating`, chapter 2.4)

```
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\rotFPbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

to get a position of the tables as wished.

So with the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  format=acmsmall, 
% review=true, 
  screen=true,
]{acmart}
%\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[%
  para,
  online,
% flushleft
]{threeparttable}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\rotFPbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \caption{Performance of LC \& HE \& FFT}\label{Performance_FFT_line_hist}
    \centering
    %\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Wall time (s)} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{BW (GB/s)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{System BW}\\
        \cline{2-4} \cline{5-9} 
        &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU}&SSD(s)&NDP2CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\
        %   &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&&CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ }\\
        \hline
        App&LC&HE&FFT&LC&HE&FFT&All&All&LC&HE&FFT\\
        \hline
        CS  &NA/0.98&NA/0.13 & NA/2.05 &NA/37.76&NA/26.15&NA/0.11  &108 &36 &36&26.15&0.11\\
        \hline
        SANS    &16.67/0&1.98/0 & 132.60/0  &2.22/$+\infty$  &1.72/$+\infty$ & 1.80e$^{-3}$/$+\infty$ &3 &36     &2.22 &1.72& 1.80e$^{-3}$ \\
        \hline
        SFNS      &13.45/0&1.14/0 &3.02/0  &2.75/$+\infty$  &2.98/$+\infty$ & 0.08/$+\infty$ &3 &36     &2.75 &2.98 &0.08  \\
        \hline
        ANS      &0.46/0&0.06/0   &3.68/0  &80.43/$+\infty$  &56.67/$+\infty$  &0.06/$+\infty$   &108 &36  &80.43&36&0.06 \\
        \hline
        FNS      &0.37/0& 0.03/0 &0.08/0  &100.00/$+\infty$ &113.33/$+\infty$ &2.91/$+\infty$  &108 &36 &100.00  &36&2.91 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable} % <=================================================
\begin{sidewaystable} % <===============================================
    \caption{Energy efficiency of  LC \& HE \& FFT }\label{Energry_comparison_FFT_Lin_His}
%   \centering
%   \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Server Only (Watt) } &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{ Energy Consumption} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Energy Efficiency}\\
            %   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ (Watt)} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}   \\
            \cline{5-6} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Watt)}&active&idle &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Joule)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(MB/Joule)} \\
            \hline
            App&LC&HE&FFT&All&All &LC&HE&FFT&LC&HE&FFT\\
            \hline
            CS &0       &0      &0       &613.70  &30.33   &601.43  &79.78 &1258.10  &63.00 &43.64 &0.19 \\
            \hline
            ANS &207.50 &207.50 &207.50 &613.70   &30.33    &109.40  &14.27 &875.21 &346.33 &243.98  &0.27\\
            \hline
            FNS &421.20 &743.40 &259.56 &613.70   &30.33    &167.07  &23.21 &23.19  &226.78 &150.00 &10.29\\
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
%   \end{threeparttable}
\vspace{0.5cm} % <======================================================
    \caption{Performance of k-NN\_2 \& k-NN\_6 \& k-NN\_8}\label{Performance_kNN_268}
%   \centering
%   \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Wall time (s)} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{BW (GB/s)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{System BW}\\
            \cline{2-4} \cline{5-9} 
            %   &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&&NDP& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\
            &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP/CPU}&SSD(s)&NDP2CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\
            %   &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}&&CPU& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(GB/s)}\\
            \hline
            k-NN\_&2&6&8&2&6&8&All&All&2&6&8\\
            \hline
            CS  & NA/17.22&NA/31.33&NA/47.45 &NA/7.55&NA/4.15&NA/2.74  &108 &36 &7.55&4.15&2.74 \\
            \hline
            SANS & 825.50/0.62  &1843/0.62&2354/0.62  & 0.16/209.68&0.07/209.68&0.06/209.68 &3 &36     &0.16&0.07&0.06 \\
            \hline
            SFNS &36.31/0.62  &34.39/0.62&32.83/0.62    & 3.58/209.68&3.78/209.68&3.96/209.68  &3 &36    &3  &3&3  \\
            \hline
            ANS &22.93/0.62     &51.21/0.62&65.40/0.62    &5.67/209.68&2.54/209.68&1.99/209.68    &108 &36  &5.67&2.54&1.99 \\
            \hline
            FNS &1.01/0.62      &0.96/0.62& 0.91/0.62     &128.71/209.68&136.42/209.68&142.86/209.68  &108 &36 &108&108&108 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        %               \begin{tablenotes}
        %%                  \footnotesize
        %%                  \item[] * can be 2, 6, or 8; $^{\mathrm{a}}$ represents k-NN.
        %               \end{tablenotes}
%   \end{threeparttable}
\vspace{0.5cm} % <======================================================
    \caption{Energy efficiency of k-NN\_2 \& k-NN\_6 \& k-NN\_8}\label{Energry_comparison_k_NN}
%   \centering
%   \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{NDP} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Server Only (Watt) } &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{ Energy Consumption} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Energy Efficiency}\\
            %& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ } &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}  &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{}   \\
            \cline{5-6} 
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Watt)}&active&idle &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{(Joule)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{(MB/Joule)} \\
            \hline
            K\-NN\_&2&6&8&All&All&2&6&8&2&6&8\\
            \hline
            CS &0&0&0 &613.70& 30.33&10568 &19227 &29120 &12.60&6.92&4.57  \\
            \hline
            ANS &207.50&207.50&207.50 &613.70& 30.33&5815.10 &12541&15916 &22.89&10.61&8.36\\
            \hline
            FNS &420.53&429.85&431.87&613.70& 30.33&817.06 &803.46&782.29 &162.93&165.68&170.17\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
%   \end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]